# How do I change the Mailchimp subscribe button color using inline CSS?

Tags: css, mailchimp

How can I use inline css to change the button and hover colors in the embedded Mailchimp form on my site [Homeschool With Love](http://www.homeschoolwithlove.com/)? I would like the background color to be #0A99AA and the hover color to be #d40000. It is a Wordpress.org site. Can you please show what code I should insert and where I should insert it? Thanks. Here's the code I have right now:

```
<div style="border-style: solid; border-width: 2px; border-color: #0A99AA;">
<!-- Begin MailChimp Signup Form -->
<link href="//cdn-images.mailchimp.com/embedcode/classic-10_7.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<style type="text/css">
#mc_embed_signup{background:#fff; clear:left; font:14px Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; }
/* Add your own MailChimp form style overrides in your site stylesheet or in this style block.
   We recommend moving this block and the preceding CSS link to the HEAD of your HTML file. */
</style>
<div id="mc_embed_signup">
<form action="//homeschoolwithlove.us13.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=74d56fdb848e8be499cc4df0e&amp;id=a119f30caa" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
<div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">
<div style="text-align: center; color: #d40000; font-size: 120%; padding-right: 10px; padding-left: 10 px;">    
<h3>Sign up for the Homeschool With Love Newsletter and get the Angel Learning Resource Pack FREE</h3>
</div>
<div class="indicates-required"><span class="asterisk">*</span> indicates required</div>
<div class="mc-field-group">
<label for="mce-EMAIL">Email Address  <span class="asterisk">*</span>
</label>
<input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="required email" id="mce-EMAIL">
</div>
<div class="mc-field-group">
<label for="mce-FNAME">First Name  <span class="asterisk">*</span>
</label>
<input type="text" value="" name="FNAME" class="required" id="mce-FNAME">
</div>
<div class="mc-field-group">
<label for="mce-LNAME">Last Name </label>
<input type="text" value="" name="LNAME" class="" id="mce-LNAME">
</div>
<div id="mce-responses" class="clear">
    <div class="response" id="mce-error-response" style="display:none">  
</div>
    <div class="response" id="mce-success-response" style="display:none"></div>
</div>    <!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->
<div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;" aria-hidden="true">
<input type="text" name="b_74d56fdb848e8be499cc4df0e_a119f30caa" tabindex="-1" value=""></div>
<div class="clear"><input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button"></div>
</div>
</form>
</div>

<!--End mc_embed_signup-->
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? It's just HTML/CSS.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

add these two lines immediately after the `#mc_embed_signup` line:

```
#mc-embedded-subscribe { background-color: #0a99a !important; }
#mc-embedded-subscribe:hover { background-color: #d40000 !important; }
```

Comment: Thank you! I had to add an extra "a" to the first color hex, but otherwise it worked perfectly! Thank you SO MUCH!